# Social network app gives error on a return line

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, runtime-error, social-networking

I was finalizing my social media application and I am consistently having the same error regarding the "**username**" of my user during the launch process of the application (app is running, user is logged in, and the next view controller fails to come up and it crashes giving `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`).

I was thinking it might be adata base problem as I had that with the the profile picture, however, the user name is in the database registered as a user with its email and password.

The code of the section the error is in:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class Post {

private var _username: String!
private var _userImg: String!
private var _postImg: String!
private var _likes: Int!
private var _postKey: String!
private var _postRef: DatabaseReference!

var username: String
{
    return _username
}

var userImg: String
{
    return _userImg
}

var postImg: String {
    get {
        return _postImg
    } set {
        _postImg = newValue


    }
}

var likes: Int {
    return _likes
}

var postKey: String {
    return _postKey
}

init(imgURl: String, likes: Int, username: String, userImg: String) {
    _likes = likes
    _postImg = imgURl
    _username = username
    _userImg = userImg
}

    init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){

    _postKey = postKey

    if let username = postData["username"] as? String {
        _username = username
    }

    if let userImg = postData["userImg"] as? String {
        _userImg = userImg
    }

    if let postImg = postData["imageUrl"] as? String{
        _postImg = postImg
        }
    if let likes = postData["likes"] as? Int {
        _likes = likes
        }
    _postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(_postKey)

}

func adjustLikes(addLikes: Bool) {

    if addLikes {

        _likes = likes + 1
    } else {

        _likes = likes - 1
    }

    _postRef.child("likes").setValue(_likes)
}

}
```

the line where the error occurs:

```
return _username
```

I am just really puzzled what the issue could be. I have looked at all the IBOutlets, as well as removing and adding new users. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `username` variable is a **computed read only** property which is returning value from variable `_username:String!`(Forced unwrapped value means can not be nil else crash ) .You need to be sure that your variable is not nil.

example when `_username` is not nil-:

```
class Foo{

    var _username:String = "tushar"
    var username: String
        {
                return _username
        }
}

var object = Foo()

print(object.username)
```

Example when your variable can get `nil` value-:

```
class Foo{

    var _username:String!
    var username: String
        {  
                print(_username)
                return _username
        }
}

var object = Foo()
print(object.username)
```

**If variable has no value in it that's a crash**

Comment: The code is already in place to hold a value in username when a user signs up. In Firebase, I can see a user I created with the username I inputted.

Comment: @user8480321 have you checked with breakpoint and print statement that it is printing value before going within computed property?

Comment: can you please show me the code I would need to write to insure the value is not nil. I am very lost right now

Answer (score 0):

In the `init(postKey:postData:)` constructor it's not guaranteed that the `_username` property will be set. However, the public `username` property is of a non-optional type `String`. My assumption is that the `username` getter tries to forcefully unwrap a `nil` value.